# Handling api response in the best way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to fetch data from API. Right now I have controller and service:

```
@RestController
public class SearcherController {

    private SearcherService searcherService;

    public SearcherController(SearcherService searcherService) {
        this.searcherService = searcherService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Output> getUrl(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new Output("BAD REQUEST"));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(searcherService.getOutput(name));
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller, I check if my request param is empty. If so I return bad request.
If it is not null I go to the service. And in service, I do the call to API.

```
@Service
public class SearcherService {

    public Output getName(String name) {

        List<Result> results = getDataFromApi(name);
    // call to Api and other calculation
    }
}
```

And fetching data from API could give me a list with results or could give me an empty list.
And that is my question.

What is the best practice? Should I move this code to controller call the API in the controller and there make `results !=null`  and do something about it?  I'm thinking about best practice in this case...

Comment: instead of returning bad request just make it required

Comment: You could throw different exceptions in your service and catch them in the rest controller and then return appropriate responses. Since it is (maybe) not the client's fault that the external API returned nothing, you might want to return a different code, e.g. 500 (503?). If there are only two cases you could also wrap your result in an Optional and work with that in the rest controller.